# code for rally Defect Arrival And Kill Rate Chart?

Tags: rally

I see that [here](https://help.rallydev.com/status-reports#arrival) there is a chart for "Defect Arrival And Kill Rate Chart." Where is the code for the same? I want to use this in my custom app.

Thanks,
Kay

Answer (score 0):

The chart is embedded into CA AC and is not available via custom apps. You may want to review the following, non-supported, app on Github: https://github.com/RallyCommunity/DefectTrendApp